# DataGrid bound to ObservableCollection of strings doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I want to add an editable `datagrid` to my view and encountered this problem. When I set the `ItemSource` property to `ObservableCollection<string>` the datagrid shows the emails, but no new line to allow users to add emails. It also doesn't support editing the values in the collection. When I try to edit email i get **System.InvalidOperationException:** 'Two-way binding requires Path or XPath'.

Then I created simple class `MyEmail` containing just one property called `Email` and used `ObservableCollection<MyEmail>` as the `ItemSource` for my datagrid. This works just fine. It supports editing and adding new emails to the datagrid.

```
public class MyEmail : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string email;
    public string Email
    {
        get => this.email;
        set
        {
            this.email = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.Email)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
```

To test this I used two same datagrids with different `ItemSource` property. One is binded to `ObservableCollection<MyEmail> Emails` and second to `ObservableCollection<string> StringEmails` like this.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyEmail> emails = new ObservableCollection<MyEmail>();
    public ObservableCollection<MyEmail> Emails
    {
        get => this.emails;
        set
        {
            this.emails = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.Emails)));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> stringEmails = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> StringEmails
    {
        get => this.stringEmails;
        set
        {
            this.stringEmails = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.Emails)));
        }
    }
```

Datagrids:

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid
        ItemsSource="{Binding Emails}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CanUserAddRows="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Emails" Binding="{Binding Path=Email}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding StringEmails}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CanUserAddRows="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="String Emails" Binding="{Binding Path=.}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Does anyone know what causes this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know what causes this behavior?

This is the expected behaviour.

For the new line to show up in the `DataGrid`, the type `T` of the `IEnumerable<T>` `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` must have a public parameterless constructor. And you cannot edit a `string` itself because it's immutable.

So you should (must) create your own custom class with properties if you want to be able to edit the data in the `DataGrid`.